# Under what conditions can TypeBuilder.CreateType return null?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

The `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` method is defined [as nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype#system-reflection-emit-typebuilder-createtype):

```cs
public Type? CreateType();
```

Under what conditions can it return null? The docs do not say.

I could dig into the source, but that would yield an untrustworthy answer (though interesting). Is there a documented explanation for this signature which I've missed?

Comment: Tracking issue on docs repo [here](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28966).

Comment: Why do you consider digging the source untrustworthy? In the source you can see a boolean field `m_isHiddenGlobalType` that controls if `CreateType()` returns null. This field is set to true in a code block commented with `// ctor for the global (module) type` https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/072d87b8c95cc7427a7a242c85d6b17950c7a074/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Emit/TypeBuilder.cs#L435

Comment: Source code is not documentation, and can change at any time in ways that can blow up your code - for behaviour to be trustworthy it must be formally documented. Nonetheless, thanks for tracking down the source, it is interesting. I've created [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/28966) on the docs repo for them to properly document this method signature.

Comment: "Source code is not documentation, and can change at any time in ways that can blow up your code - for behaviour to be trustworthy it must be formally documented." - Documentation is not a specification, and often (especially for straightforward API designs) _there is no specification_ and the public documentation just describes how the existing code behaves (i.e. so _the implementation **is** the specification_) rather than the other way around. Another approach is when _the tests are the specification_ (which is the heart of TDD).

Comment: @Dai Appreciate your comment, but disagree... I remember the days when divining the purpose of a program / library / framework / class / whatever by reading the source (or tests) was not only considered wrong, but plain bonkers. Although I agree with your comment in that it described *how things are today*, that does not make it right. Our industry used to have higher standards.

Comment: I can't agree with your sentiment, sorry. Requiring _every_ software project to have a full specification, or comprehensive documentation, regardless of the project's complexity or similarity to established patterns, would be bad project-management and result in wasted developer time. e..g there is zero point in writing a spec (or even unit-tests) for an immutable POCO class. Engineering and project-management is the art of making the right compromises. What you're suggesting would turn every 5-minute bugfix into a 30-minute spec+doc+code change, and that doesn't scale.

Comment: @Dai You're assuming I said every little thing needs to be documented. Also, we probably disagree on the meaning of documentation - I'm not referring to 80s-style 10 ton documents, printed before the software is even written. Also I never said "every" software project. There should be a balance, but right now the balance is tilted in favour of zero documentation, that was my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Inter-site-crosspost-ahoy: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/7955</sub>

---

> Under what conditions can `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` return `null`?

**TL;DR: There is no situation** when `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` will return `null` when `CreateType()` is being called by user-code. You can safely add a null-forgiving `!` to a `CreateType()` call-site.

---

The current source is at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1a296c06fff8750b4658f6f7d901347e006744d0/src/coreclr/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Emit/TypeBuilder.cs#L1853

- A quick browse of the current source  shows that `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` only returns `null` when the `TypeBuilder` is the builder for an assembly's hidden `<Module>` class.

  - The `<Module>` class is a special type that allows assemblies/modules to have eager-initialized globals.
  - The C# language itself doesn't use `<Module>`, though other languages do (e.g. C++/CLI).
  - Since C# 9.0, [you *can* now opt-in to adding `<Module>` members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers) via the `[ModuleInitializer]` attribute.
  - Of course, if you're using `Reflection.Emit` then you will have always been able to use `ModuleBuilder` going back to .NET 1.x in 2001.
- `<Module>`-building `TypeBuilder` instances cannot be directly instantiated by user-code as it requires a specific `internal TypeBuilder()` constructor invocation - instead this ctor is called only when you use the `ModuleBuilder` type.
- The only situation when `TypeBuilder.CreateType()` method *does* indeed return `null` is inside `void ModuleBuilder.CreateGlobalFunctions()`, which basically ensures that a `class <Module>` *will* be defined in the generated dynamic-assembly.
- So while the nullable annotation on `Type? TypeBuilder.CreateType()`'s return-type is technically correct <sub>([the best kind of correct](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo))</sub>, it's only there because the current API design is poor: it uses a single method for two separate use-cases when one of those cases is also `internal`-only.